Using AnyCPU DLL in mixed environments with x86/x64 specific dependencies
I have a managed code DLL with target "Any CPU" that calls SQLite. I am calling this DLL either from an x64 application or in a x86 server. SQLite needs a native DLL SQLite.Interop.DLL specific for x64 or x86:

What can I do that in any case the appropriate DLL is linked?
Edit: The image was wrong. I changed it.

If you're interacting with DLLs that are compiled for x64 (or x86) don't use Any CPU - use x64 or x86 (which will run on both 64-bit and 32-bit).

The following may be of interest: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1160645/dealing-with-bit-bit-and-any-cpu-compilation-optio and https://devopsonwindows.com/handle-platform-specific-dependencies/

Some libraries are smart enough to load the correct version of the library automatically. CharLs.Native is one such library I know about. I have no idea how SQLite handles this however.
